# nginx doesn't come up when run via SystemD

Tags: centos, nginx

I installed mainline nginx 1.13.9 using the [provided rpm](http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/centos/7/x86_64/RPMS/nginx-1.13.9-1.el7_4.ngx.x86_64.rpm) on CentOS 7.4. I had to use this rpm because I am forced to do `yum localinstall` due to company governance.

My problem is that `systemctl start nginx` always yields this:

`Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.`

journalctl tells me:

`Mar 07 08:57:05 myhost nginx[19466]: nginx: [emerg] open() "/var/opt/nginx/config/nginx.conf" failed (13: Permission denied)`

(What you see here is another company thing: I mustn't put the conf files under etc, I have to keep them in a directory where I don't need root permissions to change them)

These are the permissions set for the nginx.conf:

`-rw-r--r--. 1 nginx nginx  241 Mar  7 09:17 nginx.conf`

I reduced the nginx.conf to an (I guess) absolute minimum and even tried to put log files, pid and alike to directories where permissions are granted for sure. The error log contains absolutely nothing.

This is my reduced nginx.conf:

```
user nginx nginx;
pid /tmp/nginx.pid;
error_log /tmp/error.log debug;

events {
}

http {
  default_type application/octet-stream;
  charset      UTF-8;

  server {
    listen          8080;
    location / {
      root /tmp/;
    }
  }
}
```

And this is my slightly modified `nginx.service` definition:

```
[Unit]
Description=nginx - high performance web server
Documentation=http://nginx.org/en/docs/
After=network-online.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/var/run/nginx.pid
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -c /var/opt/nginx/config/nginx.conf -g "error_log  /tmp/error.log debug;"
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
ExecStop=/bin/kill -s TERM $MAINPID

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

(You can see that I tried to force an error_log just in case nginx fails before the nginx.conf is read)

When I do `sudo -u nginx /usr/sbin/nginx -c /var/opt/nginx/config/nginx.conf -g "error_log  /tmp/error.log debug;"` this works just fine. Despite of a short warning the process starts up fine:

```
nginx: [warn] the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /var/opt/nginx/config/nginx.conf:1
```

I am sure it must be some stupid mistake, but I have no clue which.

Comment: Stupid suggestion, but check in that all path of /var/opt/nginx/config/ is accessible to user 'nginx'. Maybe one directory in chain doesn't have enough permissions for user 'nginx'.

Comment: @YurijGoncharuk: Thanks for the suggestion. I checked this and `others` has at least `r` (var and opt) and further down the chain even `w`

Comment: Sometimes, in situations like this I login as necessary user ('nginx' in this situation) and trying to do something like read/write some files. Offcause, it's need to add possibility to login for that user (cmdline interpret is disabled by default) in /etc/passwd. It's dirty way, but sometimes is helpful for me.

Comment: @YurijGoncharuk Thanks for that suggestion, I already removed `nologin` from the user and tried `su nginx` (which has limitations) and `sudo -u nginx ...` (see above). There everything works, but not when run by SystemD

Comment: I think about it. If you have been solved problerm, please don't forget to post solution.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was caused by two mistakes I made:

- incorrect directory permissions
- a missing group membership

One of the directories was missing the `x`, so the process couldn't traverse the path. I had to `chmod g+X` it.
In addition to that I had to add the technical user of nginx (which in my scenario is not the default nginx) to the nginx group.